# How to Compare sort executions time unpredictable results in C

Tags: c, sorting, time

I am trying to write in file  the execution time of the two bellow sorts (qsort & insertion) with giving them as parameters a random array. But the results each time of the second phase of `clock() - clock()` is 0 or something that doesn't seems right. For example if i have only the calculation of insertion sort the results is right (~2800ms,2900ms...) if i have both of them the results is wrong (~2800-2900ms...) and (0ms ,15ms) where thats is impossible.

I tried to make the qsort first and then the insertion but was the same result but in other way (30ms,16ms...) and (0ms,0ms...). I think for some reason the first calculation of any sort bothering the second one with initializations or with the clock. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NO_DATA 200000

void quicksort_int(int left,int right,int *s)
{
int i,j,temp,mid,k,x;
  if(left<right)    
   {
      i=left;
      j=right;
      mid=(left+right)/2;
      x=s[mid];
          while(i<j)
          {
             while(s[i]<x) i++;
             while (s[j]>x) j--;
             if (i<j)
             {
                 if(s[i]==s[j])
                 {
                     if(i<mid) i++;
                     if(j>mid) j--;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                  temp=s[i];
                  s[i]=s[j];
                  s[j]=temp;
                 }
             }
          }
      quicksort_int(left,j-1,s);
      quicksort_int(j+1,right,s);
   }
}


void straight_insert_int(int *s,int n)
{
  for (int i=1;i<n;i++)
  {
      int x=s[i];
      int j=i-1;
      while((x<s[j])&&(j>=0))
      {
          s[j+1]=s[j];
          j=j-1; 
      }
      s[j+1]=x; 
  }  
}





int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  clock_t begin,end;
  double time_taken,time_taken2;
  FILE *fptr;
  fptr=fopen("E:\\results.txt","w");
  int *p=(int*)malloc(200000*sizeof(int));
  int *s=(int*)malloc(200000*sizeof(int));
  fprintf(fptr,"    QUICKSORT INSERTION SORT\n");
  srand(time(NULL));
 for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
 {
       if(fptr == NULL)
     {
        printf("Error!");   
        exit(1);             
     }
      for(int i=0;i<NO_DATA;i++)
      {
          p[i]=rand();
          s[i]=p[i];
      }
      begin=clock();
      straight_insert_int(p,NO_DATA);
      end=clock();
      time_taken=(double)(end-begin)*1000/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

      printf("Str_ins attempt %d Completed!\n",i);

      begin=clock();
      quicksort_int(0,NO_DATA,p);
      end=clock();
      time_taken2=(double)(end-begin)*1000/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

      printf("Quicksort attempt %d Completed!\n",i);
      fprintf(fptr,"%d.  %1d ms       %1d ms\n",i,(int)time_taken2,(int)time_taken);

 }
 fclose(fptr);
 return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I am expect the output of qsort  ALONE to be ~30ms and that's correct.
I am expect the output of insertion sorting ALONE to be ~2800ms and that's correct.
I am expect the output of insertion sorting & qsort to be  ~2800ms and ~30ms and it is ~2800ms ~0-16ms.

Comment: So I wanted to test your code and copied it [here](https://onlinegdb.com/HyM72O0qN) and got a lot of strange errors. Can you please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that others can reproduce, verify and test your assumptions? How is declared and initialized `t`? What is the definition of `quicksort_int`? `straight_insert_int`? What is `NO_DATA`? Where is `main()`? Where are `#include`s?

Comment: @Kamil Cuk Look the edited code again , the functions are no needed they are working correctly.

Comment: No, the function are needed. How am I going to check your code then? Run it through a debuger? Profile it? Inspect assembly code? There is a little point then, this is too broad. You just did `void straight_insert_int() { nanosleep((struct timespec){ .tv_nsec = rand()});` and are wondering that results are bad. The answer maybe related to CPU cache. To your compiler optimization. To your platform architecture. To some memory bootleneck. What compiler are you using, what compiler options are you using, what platform are you running on and provide an MVCE.

Comment: take a look [here](https://www.onlinegdb.com/rJWSkKA5V).

Comment: It can be IDE problem? Because is working for me too in the GDB. But in IDE the 2nd drops me 0ms... @KamilCuk

Comment: Also take srand() out of the loop or you may be reusing the same numbers, making the loop useless.

Comment: No,we don't go somewhere else. Provide a [mcve] here that can be copied, pasted, compiled, and tested. The linked article tells you how to remove unnecessary code to do so. If you can't supply a [mcve], we can't help you; the [site guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) say that questions asking for debugging help **must** include a [mcve] here, in the question itself, along with a clearly stated problem description.

Comment: look edited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're passing the same data to both functions, so you're timing a sort of random data against a sort of already sorted data.

Longer variable names don't make your code any slower, and they make it super easy to spot problems like this. Here's a corrected and refactored version.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NO_DATA 200000

void quicksort_int(int left, int right, int *s)
{
    int i, j, temp, mid, x;
    if (left < right)
    {
        i = left;
        j = right;
        mid = (left + right) / 2;
        x = s[mid];
        while (i < j)
        {
            while (s[i] < x) i++;
            while (s[j] > x) j--;
            if (i < j)
            {
                if (s[i] == s[j])
                {
                    if (i < mid) i++;
                    if (j > mid) j--;
                }
                else
                {
                    temp = s[i];
                    s[i] = s[j];
                    s[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        quicksort_int(left, j - 1, s);
        quicksort_int(j + 1, right, s);
    }
}

void straight_insert_int(int *s, int n)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        int x = s[i];
        int j = i - 1;
        while ((x < s[j]) && (j >= 0))
        {
            s[j + 1] = s[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        s[j + 1] = x;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    clock_t begin, end;
    int insertion_time_taken, qsort_time_taken;
    int *insertion_sort_data = (int *)malloc(NO_DATA * sizeof(int));
    int *qsort_data = (int *)malloc(NO_DATA * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < NO_DATA; i++)
        {
            insertion_sort_data[i] = qsort_data[i] = rand();
        }

        begin = clock();
        straight_insert_int(insertion_sort_data, NO_DATA);
        end = clock();
        insertion_time_taken = (end - begin) * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

        begin = clock();
        quicksort_int(0, NO_DATA, qsort_data);
        end = clock();
        qsort_time_taken = (end - begin) * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

        printf("%d: qsort %1d ms, insertion %1d ms\n", 
               i, qsort_time_taken, insertion_time_taken);

    }
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

On my computer the quicksort takes ~17ms and the insertion sort takes ~4500ms.